# Python Error : No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pyside2

I would like to use Python3.7 on MacOS

I already Python 2.7 version.

I created an alias on `.bash_profile`, `alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3.7"` then `source ~/.bash_profile`.

So I deleted Python2.7 to `/usr/local/lib/`

Now, when I try to execute `pip install PySide2`, I have an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I think this error has happened since I deleted Python2.7

Someone can help me to resolve my error ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because of a broken setuptools package, you just need to reinstall it.

For most operating systems: `pip install setuptools`

Linux: `apt-get install python-setuptools` or `yum install python-setuptools`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the same error when I execute `pip install setuptools`

Comment: @mutantkeyboard Thank you, that was that ! `pip3 install PySide2`.

Answer (score 8):

pyinstaller 3.6 is incompatible with setuptools 45.1.0 on python 3.7.*, should be downgraded to 45.0.0

```
pip install setuptools==45.0.0
```

can also be fixed with passing/adding hidden_imports 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' to pyinstaller spec

Issue and solutions are tracked here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1963

Comment: Can you link to a related GitHub issue?

Comment: setuptools version **45.0.0** causes some problem while using PyInstaller. Using sersion **44.0.0** will be better in that case

Answer (score 5):

I found solution from [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/91481570517707fc70aa70dca9eb986c61eac35d).

1. In my case, I open **hook-pkg_resources.py** file from the following directory:

   ```
   ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/
   ```
2. After that I added this line of code:

   ```
   hiddenimports.append('pkg_resources.py2_warn')
   ```

   between these two lines of code:

   ```
   hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pkg_resources._vendor')
   ```

   and

   ```
   excludedimports = ['__main__']
   ```
3. After that, I ran PyInstaller again and the resulted executable worked like charm.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled uppon this answer first on google when searching for this error code, so for future reference ill just leave a link to this issue that solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979390/10565375

tldr:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn example.py
```