# Mac Unable to install the "dlib"

Tags: python-3.x, macos, installation, pip, dlib

**Premise, What I want to achieve**

When I install the library "dlib", an error occurs and I cannot install it.
I would like to know the cause and how to fix it.

**source code**

```
pip install dlib
```

**problem or error message that occurs**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**what I tried**

1.Install "pkg_resources".
->The following error occurred.

```
==> Tapping homebrew/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 553959 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 553955
Receiving objects: 100% (553959/553959), 243.41 MiB | 244.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (391191/391191), done.
Tapped 3855 casks (3,971 files, 261.2MB).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
No similarly named formulae found: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "pkg_resources".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

2.Execution of "curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python" (and "pip install dlib")
[No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources)

3.Downgrade "setuptool"
[Python Error : No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035724/python-error-no-module-named-pkg-resources/60063283#60063283)

**Supplementary information**

Mac OSX

Python 3.6

I don't even understand what pkg_resources is in the first place.

Comment: Could you try and install `setuptools` package with pip using `pip install setuptools` ?

Comment: I executed it. However, I get the following message.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>.
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: then you need to reinstall python-pip package. with brew install python-pip

Comment: I executed it. However, I get the following message.

Comment: ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python-pip".

Comment: ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.

Comment: ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: try `brew uninstall python3 && brew install python3`

Comment: you seem to have a misconfigured python environment.

Comment: Thank you!!  I too think my Mac PC settings are suspect. However, I am a beginner and don't know how to find out.

Comment: I executed it. However, I get the following message.Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python3".