# I'm unable to open snowsql as it is getting errors like ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql, snowflake-task

I got this error after loading snowsql

Please help

File "PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in 
File "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Snowsql-Mac64/virtualenv_dir/snowsql/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.`enter code here`, line 627, in exec_module
File "pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 86, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue yesterday and managed to work through it by trying a bunch of different things - only I'm not sure which one made the difference.

See the last suggestion in this post for uninstalling and reinstalling PyInstaller via pip - I did that: [Pyinstaller "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres" and missing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815371/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres-and-missing-packages)

And I think the last thing I tried was 
`brew cask reinstall snowflake-snowsql`

Then you need to run the following to upgrade from v1.2:
`snowsql -v 1.2.2`

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the Snowsql 1.2.1 or 1.2.0 version and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

For AWS Platform Account :

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Linux:

https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-linux_x86_64.bash

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for MacOS:

https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-darwin_x86_64.pkg

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Windows:

https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/windows_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-windows_x86_64.msi

For Azure Platform Account:

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Linux:

https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.2-linux_x86_64.bash

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for MacOS:

https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-darwin_x86_64.pkg

Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Windows:

https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/windows_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-windows_x86_64.msi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and same error when installing via the .pkg download.  In desperation I tried installing via Homebrew Cask and it worked perfectly.