# Problems with excutables made on python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Im using pyinstaller to make a a .exe from a python script it outputs just fine but I get this error when I try to excecute.

```
  File "PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/home/arturo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
[25405] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

I have allready reinstall setuptools.

Comment: Relevant [`"Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Failed+to+execute+script+pyi_rth_pkgres%22)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the solution. It works for me on Windows 10/python 3.7.2:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me on Windows 10/Python 3.8.2.

Comment: Not wokring here. Python 3.7

Comment: Work on ubuntu 18.04 with python3.7. Standart pyinstaller from pip3.7 don't work.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815371/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres-and-missing-packages).

Basically, The steps are:

- Remove PyInstaller pip uninstall pyinstaller.
- Download the zip from [github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller).
- Unzip file.
- Make sure you are in the directory with "setup.py" and run: python setup.py install

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me--these are just instructions for uninstalling, and then reinstalling pyinstaller from a development version of GitHub.  Can you explain why you believe this to be a solution to the OP's problem?

Comment: @Iguananaut I think this can be a solution, because the missing package error is a bug in the production version, just reinstalling with pip doesn't make a difference. Everyone with this same problem install the develop version and work's

Comment: It didn't work, im not sure if the problem is caused because im trying top read a csv using files from anothger folder.

Comment: Ok, that would be worth noting (and linking to the upstream bug report if there is one).  but for what it's worth you can pip install a package directly from its source repository, e.g. like `pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following argument to your `pyinstaller` command line:

```
--hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

That fixed it me with little problems.