# Creating .exe for a kivy gui programme using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My os is windows 10. I need to create an exe for my gui programme which is made by kivy using pyinstaller. 
But when I run the exe file it gives an error like 'Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres'. 
These are the imported packages in my .py file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os
import random
```

This is the code in my .spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Ravindu\\Documents\\Lovindu\\programming\\Python\\Money_Manager\\Money_Manager_test_4\\Money_Manager_test_4.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Ravindu\\Desktop\\CashFlow'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='CashFlow',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\Ravindu\\Documents\\Lovindu\\programming\\Python\\Money_Manager\\Money_Manager_test_4\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='CashFlow')
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815371/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres-and-missing-packages) related?

Comment: I tried it too. But it did not fix my issue.