# How to turn a Python Script into exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have been trying to turn my python script into an executable the whole day. I have tried using cx-Freeze and PyInstaller but neither work. I am interested in PyInstaller now and have given up on cx-Freeze. Here is my code and I need someone to tell me whether it is even possible to turn it into executable:

```
# Importing libraries
import pygame
import random
import time

# Initializing PyGame
pygame.init()

# Setting a window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong")

# Creating a font
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
pong_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 75)
winner_font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 50)

# Set the height and width of the screen
window_width = 700
window_height = 500
size = [window_width, window_height]
game_win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
game_win2 = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


# Creating a messaging system
def message(sentence, color, x, y, font_type, display):
    sentence = font_type.render(sentence, True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


# Creating colors
white = (225, 225, 225)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (100, 100, 100)

# Setting up ball
ball_size = 25


class Ball:
    """
    Class to keep track of a ball's location and vector.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


def make_ball():
    ball = Ball()
    # Starting position of the ball.
    ball.x = 350
    ball.y = 250

    # Speed and direction of rectangle
    ball.change_x = 5
    ball.change_y = 5

    return ball


def main():
    # Scores
    left_score = 0
    right_score = 0

    pygame.init()

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    ball_list = []

    ball = make_ball()
    ball_list.append(ball)

    # Right paddle coordinates
    y = 200
    y_change = 0
    x = 50
    # Left paddle coordinates
    y1 = 200
    y1_change = 0
    x1 = 650

    while not done:
        
        # --- Event Processing
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    y_change = -7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = 7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 7

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                y_change = 0
                y1_change = 0

        y += y_change
        y1 += y1_change

        # Preventing from letting the paddle go off screen
        if y > window_height - 100:
            y -= 10
        if y < 50:
            y += 10
        if y1 > window_height - 100:
            y1 -= 10
        if y1 < 50:
            y1 += 10

        # Logic
        for ball in ball_list:
            # Move the ball's center
            ball.x += ball.change_x
            ball.y += ball.change_y

            # Bounce the ball if needed
            if ball.y > 500 - ball_size or ball.y < ball_size:
                ball.change_y *= -1
            if ball.x > window_width - ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                left_score += 1
            if ball.x < ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                right_score += 1

            ball_rect = pygame.Rect(ball.x - ball_size, ball.y - ball_size, ball_size * 2, ball_size * 2)

            left_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x < 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(left_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = abs(ball.change_x)

            right_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x > 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(right_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = -abs(ball.change_x)

            if right_score == 10:
                message("RIGHT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 60, 250, winner_font, game_win)
                pygame.display.flip()
                pygame.event.poll()
                time.sleep(5)
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif left_score == 10:
                message("LEFT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 60, 250, winner_font, game_win)
                pygame.display.flip()
                pygame.event.poll()
                time.sleep(5)
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # Drawing
        # Set the screen background
        game_win.fill(black)

        # Draw the balls
        for ball in ball_list:
            pygame.draw.circle(game_win, white, [ball.x, ball.y], ball_size)

        # Creating Scoreboard
        message("Left player score: " + str(left_score), white, 10, 10, font, game_win)
        message("Right player score: " + str(right_score), white, 490, 10, font, game_win)

        # Drawing a left paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x, y, 25, 100])
        # Drawing a right paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x1, y1, 25, 100])

        # Setting FPS
        FPS = pygame.time.Clock()
        FPS.tick(60)

        # Updating so actions take place
        pygame.display.flip()


while True:
    game_win2.fill(black)
    pygame.event.poll()     
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    message("Pong", white, 280, 100, pong_font, game_win2)
    if 150 + 100 > mouse[0] > 150 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [150, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            break
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [150, 350, 100, 50])

    if 450 + 100 > mouse[0] > 450 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [450, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [450, 350, 100, 50])

    message("Start", black, 175, 367, font, game_win2)
    message("Quit", black, 475, 367, font, game_win2)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Wrap-up
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You don't need to be bothered that much about the code. But I need help with turning it into an executable using pyinstaller.

Comment: "Neither work" = what exactly?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi When I open an executable that was "Processed" by cx-Freeze, it opens for a second and then closes immediately. The same goes for pyinstaller. :(

Comment: Can you run them from the terminal directly? Or make your code log to a file rather than error to stderr?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have tried everything, running from a terminal, using PyCharm

Comment: I meant your exe files, not the Python code

Comment: what does that mean? I am new to PyInstaller

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you find a method of turning this code into an executable and can you also include some instructions? Because I don't know why but it isn't working for me

Comment: @snoopstick, they want you to open command prompt in the folder with the exe file and run the exe file from the command prompt. It looks like your program finishes running as soon as it starts, which is why the cmd it opens closes immediately. If you open cmd separately from the exe, cmd will stay open after your program exits

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I get it but the problem is with the exe, not the code

Comment: Exactly. Run the EXE in the terminal... It should show your error for long enough you to copy and put it in your question

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok got it. Wait a little bit and I will be back

Comment: @OneCricketeer OK now I am done so it gave me this popup: `Fatal Error Detected` `Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres`. What does this mean

Comment: I am on Window 10 by the way

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you reply soon I need help

Comment: IDK what that script is...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815371/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres-and-missing-packages

Comment: @snoopstick Please copy the _entire_ traceback and edit it into your question. The pkg_resources runtime hook can fail due to any number of reasons.

Comment: @Legorooj The link OneCricketeer send seems useful. I will return and tell whether it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of common things that could cause issues with `pygame` and `pyinstaller`:

1. Update `pygame` to `2.0.0.dev6` (`pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`) if you have not already.
2. When making `.exe` try with following: `pyinstaller -w --onefile main.py`
   Always change the `.py` file you want to convert to `main.py`
   -> (`-w` without console)
   NOTE: you need to navigate to `main.py` path first
3. The `.exe` file will be in the `dist` folder so paths will be invalid, make sure to move it to the same folder where your initial `main.py` is.
4. Fonts also cause problems, if problem persists, try removing them completely. If everything works fine, consider changing the font (Arial always worked for me), or copy font you want to use to the folder where your `.exe` is

Comment: Well, it worked out when I tried the font thing. Arial does work and there is another one called Consolas which also seems to work!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you want some specific try putting its `.ttf` into the folder